# Globally delimit numbers in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Is it possible to format all numbers in a rails app to be delimited?

I don't really think this is an i18n issue, as I'm fine with the default delimiter/separator characters. I'm simply trying to avoid putting number_with_delimiter(value) all over my views.

I always want numbers to be displayed as delimited. Always.

So far I've tried extending the Fixnum class with code cribbed from the number_with_delimiter method:

```
class Fixnum

  def delimit(delimiter=",", separator=".")
    begin
      parts = self.to_s.split('.')
      parts[0].gsub!(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/, "\\1#{delimiter}")
      parts.join separator
    rescue
      self
    end
  end 
end
```

`> 98734578.delimit
 => "98,734,578"`

`> 223.delimit => "223"`

So this is a step in the right direction- I like the dot notation as well as the slightly shorter method name. But I'd like to apply this to all instances of a Fixnum inside of a view without having to call `.delimit`.

Is this a bad idea? Should I be worried about implications this will have on numbers outside of the view context? Is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Comment: nope. this is the dynamic nature of Ruby's open classes. It should be used with caution on Ruby core classes (often referred to as monkeypatching) but if all you're doing is adding to a class and not overriding existing functionality (i.e. to_s on String) you should be golden. Although keep in mind Rails has helpers for this already.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html

Comment: use number_with_delimeter helper method for it. [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_delimiter)

Comment: @engineerDave right thanks Dave. I am aware of of the Rails NumberHelpers, but I was hoping to essentially apply the number_with_delimiter() as a default to every instance of a number in my app, rather than one by one in views